# Why are there greyed / dimmed / faded questions now?

Tags: support, questions

I just refreshed the [iphone]-tag-site, and I'm seeing all kinds of questions with what appears to be a grey overlay (see image). What is this for/why am I seeing this? I have never seen anything like this before..

[image: Grey overlay on q 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've added a tag that the question uses to your ignore list. Any question which has ignored tags gets "faded" so you know it's probably not something you're interested in.

This is similar to how questions with tags you favorited get highlighted. If the quesiton contains both tags which are favorited *and* ignored, it will get highlighted yellow *and* faded.

See [What do all the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22185/141525) for more information.

Comment: Oh, wow, I really didn't realize that. I must have added a tag to the ignore-list by accident then. Thank you!

Comment: what about answers? I sometimes see faded answers.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're ignoring one or more of the tags on the question. You can manage your ignored tags by going to your profile and clicking on "prefs" next to "edit".